# Permit only Admin users to mount Windows partition

Tags: permissions, mount

I have Ubuntu installed along with Win-7. In the Ubuntu File manager under Devices there is an entry with my computer name. Clicking that selection mounts the Windows partition.

What I'd like to accomplish:
I would like the Admin level users to be able to use the menu as described above. However, I would like to not permit Standard Users to mount the partition or even have the mount point visible on the File manager menu.

I've tried various methods described on this forum and on other internet searches that involve modifying fstab, but none gave me the results I'm looking for. What is the correct method for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/fstab` file, the mounting permissions are in there, it sounds like a user like has been added for those filesystems you wish to be root mountable only.

The manual page has more info

https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the drive partition is not being loaded in fstab. The partition is being displayed by the File Manager from a link in /dev/disks/by-label.

Comment: The partition is being displayed by the File Manager is from a link in /dev/disks/by-label. , which points to /sda1.
The link appears to be loaded automatically when Ubuntu starts up. Changing permissions on either the link or sda1 had no effect on visibility.
Also, more info this is Ubuntu 14.04.
So, the question still remains, how would I hide this partition as described above in the original question?